# Dotnetnuke and gzip

Tags: frameworks, gzip, dotnetnuke

I am currently running Dotnetnuke version 4.9.4 and would like to enable gzip compression. My concern is that IE6 prior to SP2 has known issues with gzipped content. Does the Dotnetnuke framework handle the gzip issues with IE6 or will I need to apply a fix outside of the framework?

Comment: Easy fix, don't support ancient browsers such as IE6

Comment: The problem you mention (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837251) only relates to IE6 SP1 which was released in 2002.  

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_6#Release_history

The fix has been available to IE6 users for 7 years.  Are you sure you care to resolve this?

Comment: Not to mention that Windows Update would have downloaded this fix years ago as well.  So not only are your users locked into IE6 SP1 but they haven't had a security patch since 2002.

Comment: What % of your users are running IE6 SP1?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I didn't even think about the fact that SP1 was 7 years ago. I'll take the time to resolve this later if it becomes an issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's the web server that does the gzip stuff, not DNN itself.

[How to enable Gzip in IIS](http://dnngallery.net/blog/id/165/improve-dotnetnuke-performance-with-gzip-compression-in-iis)

Also, if you're that worried about IE6 people, don't enable Gzip. Personally, I would prefer to use it for the rest of the people and ignore those who are still living in the dark ages. Unless of course the majority of your users use that version of IE6 in which case you don't really have a choice.